# Only have delete show on certain UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am working on an app right now where I want to be able to delete some things from a UITableView upon clicking a delete button.  Right now I am able to get the edit button working to show the circle with line through it to show you can delete but there are a couple of cells that I don't want the user to be able to delete.  Does anyone know an easy way of implementing this.  If you look at this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlKgw.jpg) it shows all three of my cells with the delete showing but I only want the first two to move and the last one to not move at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override this method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ({SOMETHING TO SAY IF THIS CELL CAN NOT BE DELETED}) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you want to override is

```
tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

Read up on the [`UITableViewDataSource` Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acommitEditingStyle%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a). From the discussion of this method:

> When users tap the insertion (green plus) control or Delete button
>   associated with a `UITableViewCell` object in the table view, the table
>   view sends this message to the data source, asking it to commit the
>   change. (If the user taps the deletion (red minus) control, the table
>   view then displays the Delete button to get confirmation.) The data
>   source commits the insertion or deletion by invoking the `UITableView`
>   methods `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or
>   `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`, as appropriate.

Comment: Yeah that will allow me to not allow the user to delete the row, but is there a way to just not even have the red circle even show up? I just don't even want the user to attempt to remove the row.  I only want certain rows to show the red circle and not all of the rows.  And i know i can hide the red circle but I don't even want the cell to slide over.  I only want the cells that move to be the ones that can be deleted.

Comment: @mrbaker: Interesting question. I'm not sure if that's possible (I'm thinking not), but I'll get back to you if I discover otherwise.

Comment: thanks. yeah i just feel like there should be a way but i am not entirely sure.  I was thinking about creating custom cells that don't move and constantly show a uiview but am not entirely sure that will work either.